# Fix for : System.Web.HttpException: The file has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

We published our website and everything worked fine. After few days, something strange happened. we're getting "The file 'xxx.cshtml' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested."

Resetting application pool, even restarting IIS didn’t help us to resolve the problem. Even resetting the Web server machine didn't fix the problem. but when we re-copying the published files again, web site starts working again.
We compared the problem website files with the new files, all are the same. nothing is missing. so every two-three days, we are getting the same error and the only way we can fix it is recopying the files again.

We even copied website when we got an error and then create another website based on those files and it works fine!
Any suggestion what can cause this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Did you work this problem out? We have just experienced the same thing on a live web server. Everything working for a couple of days, and then suddenly this error started being thrown. A deploy of the same code also fixed it for us, but we are trying to investigate the cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### About the error

> **System.Web.HttpException: The file has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested**
>   This error will come when a reference is specified in web.config and
>   deployment folder/site does not contain these dlls installed in the
>   system or bin folder does not contain them(if they are private
>   assemblies). For Example: (add assembly="Namespace1.NameSpace2,
>   Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/)
>   if your web.config contains any assemblies like this and deployed
>   server doesnot contain these assembiles in bin or GAC, then this error
>   will occur.

---

### Scenarios:

Here are some possible scenarios that will generate this error:

1. When we publish the website with the "updateable" check OFF and then
   copy some files on deployment location that has some markup or code in them. By
   putting the "updateable" check OFF we instruct the asp.net compiler to compile all the markup and code into dll files so that further on asp.net would not consider runtime compilation of content. But if it needs to (due to the presence of such content) it will throw that error.
2. The second situation is when we have a web application configured in
   VS.Net to run directly off IIS (the http project) and then we publish it to the same location again with the "updateable" checked OFF. There will be development files at same location which will cause similar errors.
3. Another situation is where we have a precompiled website and within the
   root folder of it we have another folder that has content for another asp.net
   application but isnÂ¡Â¯t marked as application in IIS. ASP.Net tracks asp.net
   applications when running on IIS by virtual directories in IIS marked as applications. A child folder having un-compiled content within a parent
   application which is precompiled will again cause this error.

*Source: Microsoft Support*

Apparently, it is another scenario where the cause is related to missing ReportViewer .dll references

---

### Solutions

- [Some people](https://forums.asp.net/t/956297.aspx) talks about adding manually the missing missing assembly files.

> i found out one thing that while publishing the application it does
>   not copy all of the dependent assemblies in the bin folder.So i just
>   copied them manually to the server and now every thing is working

- Other people, somehow fixed this installing "Microsoft Web Service Enhancements v3.0". [Downlaod here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14089). It probably provides missing required .dll
- [Here](https://forums.asp.net/t/956297.aspx), somebody fixed it, enabling "Create a separate assembly for each page and control output" in the Deployment Options

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we already compared references and the same version worked for 1 month.This issue just started recently.